# Extra element in def function

Tags: python

So, that`s my code:

```
def city_country(f_city, f_country, s_city, s_country, t_city, t_country):
    print(f"{f_city.title()}, {f_country.title()}")
    print(f"{s_city.title()}, {s_country.upper()}")
    print(f"{t_city.title()}, {t_country.title()}")
    if f_country == 'usa' or f_country == 'Usa':
        print(f"{f_country.upper()}")
    elif s_country == 'usa' or s_country == 'Usa':
        print(f"{s_country.upper()}")
    elif t_country == 'usa' or t_country == 'Usa':
        print(f"{t_country.upper()}")
    return 
city_country('moscow', 'russia', 'washington', 'usa', 'berlin', 'germany')
```

and everything would be fine, but for some reason I have an extra element displayed at the end in the output of the function:

```
Moscow, Russia
Washington, USA
Berlin, Germany
USA
```

Any assumptions?

Comment: why do you think you have ab extra element displayed? please explain

Answer (score 0):

It is because of following comparison

```
elif s_country == 'usa' or s_country == 'Usa':
      print(f"{s_country.upper()}")
```

And from input you have passed `usa` to `s_country` variable

Comment: It looks like you have intentionally put all those comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @John Byro

If you want your code to output:

> Moscow, Russia

> Washington, USA

> Berlin, Germany

But USA should be capitalized wherever it occurs, whether in F_country, s_country, or t_country use this code with fixed capitalization no matter what you enter for country name:

```
def city_country(f_city, f_country, s_city, s_country, t_city, t_country):
    capitalizedList = []
    for country in [f_country, s_country, t_country]:
        if( country.lower() == 'usa' ):
            country = country.upper()
        else:
            country  = country.title()
        capitalizedList.append(country)
        
    print(f"{f_city.title()}, {capitalizedList[0]}")
    print(f"{s_city.title()}, {capitalizedList[1]}")
    print(f"{t_city.title()}, {capitalizedList[2]}")
    print()
    return 

#Method Call Test Cases
city_country('moscow', 'russia', 'washington', 'usa', 'berlin', 'germany')

city_country('moscow', 'UsA', 'washington', 'usa', 'berlin', 'usa')

city_country('Los Angeles', 'USA', 'washington', 'usa', 'berlin', 'GermANY')
```

[You can see the output here](https://www.online-python.com/KrVL0Wko8w)

Comment: Okay, but if I want that not only s_country should be "USA"? I want to edit this def function so that both f_country and t_country can display not only countries with a capital letter, but also display some countries with .upper for complete correctness.

Comment: @k77 So I take what you are looking to capitalize USA whenever it occurs, but not any other country name? I will update the code then